# Are general health-related question on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I saw in the help center that

> personal medical questions and health advice

are off-topic.

Does "personal" pertain to both "medical questions" and "health advice"? In other words, is a "health advice" (general, not personal) on topic?

I am looking for recommended / standard bio tests for men aged ~45-55 and would like to make sure this is (or not) appropriate for this site.

Comment: I'd reckon you're better off at Health. SE, either way.

Comment: Agree with AliceD, that sounds more like Health.SE. Questions about *underlying biology* are fine here. Health advice isn't, in part because there isn't really any such thing as "impersonal health advice" besides very generic advice not appropriate here.

Comment: You could *possibly* ask which body systems/features/functionalities begin to significantly diminish after a specific age, and what the primary reason is.. but even then, that may be too open ended, since each and every person is different, and such a generalization may not be so immediately practical and/or relavent.